# Big Query: Compute Months Between Two Dates Which are Strings

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working in Big Query with a table. Two of the columns, Date1 and Date2, are supposed to be dates but they are strings in the 'YYYYMM' format.

I would like to compute the number of months between these two dates.

For example, if Date1 was '202106' and Date2 was '201901', the result would be 29.

My data table has approximately 500,000 rows.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
select date_diff(
  cast(Date1 as date format 'YYYYMM'), 
  cast(Date2 as date format 'YYYYMM')
, month)
```

If t apply to sample data in your question ( if Date1 was '202106' and Date2 was '201901',) - output is

[image]

Comment: `Format clause for CAST` was release few days ago - you can see details [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#formatting_syntax)